# Rsyslog and resolving (nameservers) delay

Tags: dns, delay, nameservers, rsyslog

When nameservers are being declared in etc/resolv.conf, rsyslog shows a significant delay while parsing incoming log events.

I suppose this happens because DNS resolving takes place for each processed event.

When nameservers are not declared in resolv.conf, rsyslog works like a charm.

Here comes the dilemma.

I need DNS queries for my web application (hosted in the same server) to be fully functional but when i declare nameservers in resolv.conf, rsyslog has a hard time.

What should i do?

Thank you,

Apostolos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default rsyslog does a reverse dns lookup on every log that comes through. Simply disable the reverse lookup in rsyslog. The option to start rsyslog with is "-x" to disable dns lookups.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd